# Unable to sign bootstrapper executable (setup.exe) after embeding manifest

Tags: clickonce, signing, bootstrapper, signtool, mt

We are using Nant to prepare setup of our software using Clickonce.

Using signtool to sign dll(s) and exe(s).

**signtool command** : `signtool sign /f ${certFile} /p ${certFilePwd} {path of setup.exe}`

Using **Mt.exe** to embed manifests in exe files.

**Mt command** : `mt -manifest {manifest file} -outputresource:{filepath};#1`

We have two exe files. One is our app.exe and second is setup.exe(bootstrapper created by clickonce)

There is no issue with app.exe in signing after embedding manifests.

But signing of setup.exe **after embedding** manifest is giving below error:

`SignTool Error: SignedCode::Sign returned error: 0x80070057. The parameter is incorrect.`

manifest file contains:

```xml
<assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0"> 
    <ms_asmv2:trustInfo xmlns:ms_asmv2="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2">
        <ms_asmv2:security>
            <ms_asmv2:requestedPrivileges>
                <ms_asmv2:requestedExecutionLevel level="asInvoker" 
                           uiAccess="false"></ms_asmv2:requestedExecutionLevel>
            </ms_asmv2:requestedPrivileges>
        </ms_asmv2:security>
    </ms_asmv2:trustInfo>
</assembly>
```

No error if I do sign before embedding manifest but it cant work as any file needs resigning after changes.

I also tried following steps:

1. sign setup.exe
2. embed manifests
3. resign setup.exe (same error during this step as above)

Does any have solution/workaround of this problem?

Comment: seems that no solution/workaround

Comment: Did you try re-signing the manifest with mage? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xc3tc5xx.aspx

Comment: yes, it gives error. I think mage can not be used to sign an exe, it is used to sign application manifests and .application file

Answer (score 1):

I can't find a source to cite, but I ran into a similar problem a while ago and you can't sign a setup.exe that has been previously signed. You can generate your bootstrapper from scratch ([see MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms164294.aspx)), apply your manifest and then sign it (for the first time!) and it should work.

Comment: It would help if signtool actually told us this! Using mt.exe was a red herring for me - I signed, ran mt.exe, realised the signing had gone, signed it again, and came up with this obscure error message. Thankfully you pointed out the reason so thanks.

Answer (score 0):

## Conclusion

> Sometimes, an **obfuscator tool** produced an **un-signable** file. meaning, the *signtool* was returning error 0x80070057 for anything I tried.
>
> I've also noticed that the **Version** and **Language** properties are blank on the 'invalid' file see [image: first DLL is valid while the second one is not]
>
> So, my conclusion is that it's an issue with the **file itself** and not with the sign tool or sign server.

## How I got to this conclusion

### I tried all the answers suggested:

- In this page
- [signtool failing to dual sign SHA2 and SHA1 with timestamps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18542160/signtool-failing-to-dual-sign-sha2-and-sha1-with-timestamps)
- [How does one correctly dual-sign code with a timestamp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20601575/how-does-one-correctly-dual-sign-code-with-a-timestamp)

### I tried with multiple sign servers:

- http://timestamp.digicert.com
- http://tsa.starfieldtech.com
- http://timestamp.verisign.com
- http://timestamp.globalsign.com
- http://sha256timestamp.ws.symantec.com
- http://timestamp.comodoca.com
- http://timestamp.geotrust.com