# signtool failing to dual sign SHA2 and SHA1 with timestamps

Tags: windows, sha256, authenticode, signtool, verisign

We need to dual sign our binaries with SHA1 and SHA2 using signtool.exe, our certificate supports 256-bit SHA2.

Using the Windows 8 SDK's signtool:

e.g.:

signtool.exe sign /as /fd sha256 /t http://timestamp.verisign.com/scripts/timstamp.dll /f "certificate.pfx" /p XXXXXXX "file.dll"

(where XXXXXXX is our password for the certificate)

fails with the cryptic error:

SignTool Error: SignedCode::Sign returned error: 0x80070057
        The parameter is incorrect.
SignTool Error: An error occurred while attempting to sign: file.dll

Signing without a timestamp works, signing individually as SHA1 or SHA256 works, but we need to dual sign, and imagine not having a timestamp is a no no.

I've tried the 32 and 64-bit versions of signtool.exe, tried it on a Win7 and Win8 machine, and tried playing around with the command line options but to no avail.  Has anyone hit on this issue before?

Answer (score 19):

I know it's a bit old, but I landed in this thread and maybe someone else will too.

It will work if you sign first with SHA1 and then with SHA256:

```
signtool.exe sign /f cert_file.pfx /t http://timestamp.comodoca.com/authenticode /p cert_password
signtool.exe sign /f cert_file.pfx /as /fd sha256 /tr http://timestamp.comodoca.com/rfc3161 /td sha256 /p cert_password
```

It worked using the same certificate in both signatures. I used the signtool from Windows 10 SDK, don't know if it will work with previous versions.

Comment: Thanks, this helped! It worked for me with and MIS using signtool Windows 8.1 SDK as long as I did it in this order. The MSI shows trusted on Windows 2008.

Comment: [This](http://support.ksoftware.net/support/solutions/articles/215805-the-truth-about-sha1-sha-256-and-code-signing-certificates-) says "Note that you do need the 6.3 version of Signtool to do this. It comes with the Windows 8.1 SDK".

Answer (score 18):

I've been trying to do this exact thing, and found the following did the trick. This approach relies on using two Authenticode certificates, one for SHA-1 and another for SHA-256, in order to ensure the files are accepted as valid by Windows Vista and Windows Server 2008 which do not support being signed by a SHA-256 certificate even if the SHA-1 algorithm is used:

```
signtool.exe sign /sha1 SHA1_Thumprint /v /d "FileDescription" /du "CompanyURL" /fd sha1 /tr http://timestamp.comodoca.com/rfc3161 /td sha1 "FileName.dll"
signtool.exe sign /sha1 SHA256_Thumprint /as /v /d "FileDescription" /du "CompanyURL" /fd sha256 /tr http://timestamp.comodoca.com/rfc3161 /td sha256 "FileName.dll"
```

Note that the SHA-1 thumbprints are explicitly specified for each signing step using the `/sha1` switch and that `/as` is used to *append* the SHA-256 signature. Otherwise the SHA-256 signature will override the SHA-1 signature.

The other gotcha I found in the process was that only DLLs and EXEs support dual signatures. MSI installers do not.

*Updated 29/12/15*:

The format of the SHA-1/SHA-256 thumbprint is a 40-character hexadecimal upper case string with no spaces. For example:

```
signtool.exe sign /sha1 0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF01234567 /as /v /d "FileDescription" /du "CompanyURL" /fd sha256 /tr http://timestamp.comodoca.com/rfc3161 /td sha256 "FileName.dll"
```

*Updated 30/12/2015*

To sign an MSI file with a SHA-256 certificate but with a SHA-1 hash use a command similar to the below:

```
signtool.exe sign /sha1 SHA256_Thumprint /v /d "FileDescription" /du "CompanyURL" /t http://timestamp.comodoca.com/authenticode "FileName.msi"
```

Comment: does this mean, one needs to buy two different certificates? or is it enough to copy and rename?

Comment: Yes it does unfortunately (unless anyone knows better). I couldn't get a SHA-256 certificate used to generate a SHA-1 signature to be accepted as valid on Windows Server 2008.

Comment: Any chance you could update with the *format* of the thumbprint? Simply copying the string from certmgr.msc doesn't work.

Comment: I'll update with a comment about that. From memory it's all capitals and with no spaces.

Comment: I'm wondering what's the `/du` command switch for? I know that it adds a URL, but where is it used? I don't see it anywhere in the signature or in the UAC popup.

Comment: I think it's not fully shown in the Windows UI anymore, but if I look at the Advanced tab for the .NET host which is Authenticode signed on my machine, I can see a URL within the `1.3.6.1.4.1.311.2.1.12` authenticated attribute of `http://www.microsoft.com`.

Answer (score 6):

The issue is actually way simpler.

The problem is with the time stamp server.

Instead of using **signtool.exe** with this

```
/t http://timestamp.comodoca.com
```

You need to use it like this for SHA1

```
/tr http://timestamp.comodoca.com /td sha1
```

And for SHA256

```
/tr http://timestamp.comodoca.com/?td=sha256 /td sha256
```

Answer (score 3):

Try using

```
signtool.exe sign /as /fd sha256 /tr http://timestamp.geotrust.com /td sha256 /f certificate.pfx /p XXXXXX file.dll
```

/tr is for RFC3161 timestamping, /td obviously for the hash to use.

Answer (score 2):

Adding to martin_costello answer, XP and Vista do not support the RFC timestamp. You need to use the /t option for sha1 signatures.

```
signtool.exe sign /sha1 SHA1_Thumprint /v /d "FileDescription" /du "CompanyURL" /fd sha1 /t http://timestamp.verisign.com/scripts/timestamp.dll "FileName.dll"
signtool.exe sign /sha1 SHA256_Thumprint /as /v /d "FileDescription" /du "CompanyURL" /fd sha256 /tr http://timestamp.comodoca.com/rfc3161 /td sha256 "FileName.dll"
```

Answer (score 1):

I also get the above error, however It works with the [osslsigncode](http://osslsigncode.sourceforge.net/) utility when using the '-nest' option:

```
osslsigncode sign -pkcs12 cert1.pfx -h sha1 -t http://timestamp.verisign.com/scripts/timestamp.dll -in original.exe -out intermediate.exe
osslsigncode sign -pkcs12 cert2.pfx -nest -h sha1 -t http://timestamp.verisign.com/scripts/timestamp.dll -in intermediate.exe -out final.exe
```

The official project is for Unix, however I've knocked up my own [windows fork](http://sourceforge.net/u/keeely/osslsigncode/ci/master/tree/).

Answer (score 0):

I think [this link](http://support.ksoftware.net/support/solutions/articles/215805-the-truth-about-sha1-sha-256-and-code-signing-certificates-) has some nice pointers. Some of it is mentioned in the answer by martin_costello, but this article provides some more details. In particular:

- 'Dual signing and include an SHA1 file digest' is possible if you sign SHA1 first, and use /as for the SHA256. It only works with signtool v6.3 from the Windows 8.1 SDK (or later) though.
- Dual signing with 'a FULL SHA1 signature', needed for windows version before XP sp3, requires 2 different certificates.

(I haven't tested all this myself though.)