# How to Code Sign with multiple timestamps - my stamps get overwritten

Tags: timestamp, code-signing, signtool

### Problem

Though I am getting no error on verbose SignTool ([manual](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/signtool-exe)) commands on my windows executable, the timestamps get overwritten, and I wish there to be multiple timestamps, is that possible?

- If it ***is*** possible, then how?
- If it ***is not*** possible, and I have to use only 1 single timestamp, then which server would you recommend in the long run? ([DigiCert](https://www.digicert.com/code-signing/signcode-signtool-command-line.htm) is coming to my mind now.)

---

### Here's what I tried

PowerShell function

```powershell
function sign32exe([string]$arg)
{
    & 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\x86\signtool.exe' sign /fd sha256 /a $arg
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 5
    & 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\x86\signtool.exe' timestamp /tr http://timestamp.globalsign.com/?signature=sha2 /td sha256 /v $arg
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 5
    & 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\x86\signtool.exe' timestamp /tr http://sha256timestamp.ws.symantec.com/sha256/timestamp /td sha256 /v $arg
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 5
    & 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\x86\signtool.exe' timestamp /tr http://time.certum.pl /td sha256 /v $arg
}
```

---

### PowerShell output

I get positive output from SignTool, but the timestamps get overwritten by each invocation (restructured for better readability):

The signing process goes well:

```
Done Adding Additional Store
Successfully signed: .\my.exe
```

Followed by the timestamping, which individually go without a problem:

```
Successfully timestamped: .\my.exe
Number of files successfully timestamped: 1
Number of errors: 0

Successfully timestamped: .\my.exe
Number of files successfully timestamped: 1
Number of errors: 0

Successfully timestamped: .\my.exe
Number of files successfully timestamped: 1
Number of errors: 0
```

---

### Image for the words

[image: only the last timestamp present]

---

### Rationale

The certificate I own is from Certum authority, called [Standard Code Signing](https://www.certum.eu/en/cert_offer_en_standard_code_signing/). Since it expires soon, I'd like to ensure my windows executable does not get into trouble after my signing certificate expiration. I thought more timestamps would be better in case one server becomes unavailable in time or the service stops, an example of this could be that Certum authority would disappear for instance.

---

### Additional detail

My ideal solution should solve the above problem:

- by timestamping with more than one server; or
- by quoting some credible source on that it is not possible

Comment: "Since it expires soon, I'd like to ensure my windows executable does not get into trouble after my signing certificate expiration. I thought more timestamps would be better in case one server becomes unavailable in time or the service stops" - I totally do *not* understand what you mean. How does the future expiration of your certificate relate to the timestamps of existing signatures? Notice that the TSA does not need to be involved in future validations of the timestamp: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trusted_timestamping#Checking_the_timestamp

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This question looks like a duplicate of [Code Signing with Multiple Timestamp servers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20912013/code-signing-with-multiple-timestamp-servers).

The short answer is: no, it's not possible to timestamp more than once.

It's possible however to sign with different algorithms (dual-sign), but it means that there will be two separate signatures generated, each with its own timestamp.

What would multiple timestamps mean, actually? A timestamp tells the consumer when the asset was signed. It's not possible that the single action of signing was done in two separate moments. Unless there are two different signatures applied, each with own timestamp (dual-sign).

Also, let's imagine that it's possible to apply two timestamps to the same signature. Let's say that the file is signed on 1/1/2019, the first timestamp is applied on 2/1/2019, and the second timestamp on 3/3/2020. What would it mean for a client that verifies the signature? It wouldn't really make much sense, would it? Only the latter timestamp really matters, if the certificate is still valid - that's why SignTool overrides the previous timestamp.

Btw, there is a lot of articles about timestamping in general, none of them mentions assigning more than one timestamp to a certificate, e.g.:

- https://www.digicert.com/blog/best-practices-timestamping/
- https://www.ssl2buy.com/wiki/timestamping-why-digital-signatures-need-timestamps
- https://www.secureblackbox.com/kb/articles/11-TimeStamping.rst

Comment: Exactly! This is not a question of technical feasibility but it is crystal clear that what the OP wants just does not make any sense. A signature cannot happen at two points in time but exactly once, which is what timestamp services were invented for in the first place. The question is a typical example of the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/309898): The author describes **how** he wants to solve a problem rather than **which** problem it is he likes to solve. (Well okay, he is mentioning his rationale, so it is just 80% XY.)