# How to get a list of all certificates in a file?

Tags: c++, windows, cryptoapi

I would like to be able to open a file and grab a list of all the certificates for that file, and list off all key information for each certificate.

*Currently, I have the listing of key information done correctly for the first certificate listed from `CryptQueryObject()`, but I cannot find any way of getting a list of all the certificates.*

[Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms148497%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is what I would like to use, but I cannot use .NET and I would not like to be restricted to Windows 8/Server 2012 which the solution from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24892531/reading-multiple-signatures-from-executable-file) would do.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reading multiple signatures from executable file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24892531/reading-multiple-signatures-from-executable-file)