# How to convert OID of a code-signing algorithm from CRYPT_ALGORITHM_IDENTIFIER to a human readable string?

Tags: c++, winapi, code-signing, digital-certificate

When I'm [retrieving a code signing signature](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/323809/how-to-get-information-from-authenticode-signed-executables) from an executable file on Windows, the [`CERT_CONTEXT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa377189(v=vs.85).aspx) of the certificate points to the [`CERT_INFO`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa377200(v=vs.85).aspx), that has `CRYPT_ALGORITHM_IDENTIFIER SignatureAlgorithm` member that contains the algorithm used for signing.

How do I convert that to a human readable form as such?

[image]

For instance, `SignatureAlgorithm.pszObjId` may be set to `"1.2.840.113549.1.1.11"` string, which is `szOID_RSA_SHA256RSA` according to [this long list](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa381133(v=vs.85).aspx). I guess I can make a very long switch statement for it, and link it to `"sha256"`, but I'd rather avoid it since I don't know what most of those values are. Is there an API that can do all that for me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`CryptFindOIDInfo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379938(v=vs.85).aspx) to get information about a OID including the display name and the CNG algorithm identifier string:

```
void PrintSigAlgoName(CRYPT_ALGORITHM_IDENTIFIER* pSigAlgo)
{
    if(pSigAlgo && pSigAlgo->pszObjId)
    {
        PCCRYPT_OID_INFO pCOI = CryptFindOIDInfo(CRYPT_OID_INFO_OID_KEY, pSigAlgo->pszObjId, 0);
        if(pCOI && pCOI->pwszName)
        {
            _tprintf(_T("%ls"), pCOI->pwszName);
        }
        else
        {
            _tprintf(_T("%hs"), pSigAlgo->pszObjId);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. It worked. Although it would be nice to have a code example for that function. It's not easy to follow how exactly to use it. Wanna copy it from my edited answer above and I'll mark it here?

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on the [answer of Anders](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50975128/7571258). You can also get this information from the result of a call to `WinVerifyTrust()`. It is deeply nested inside `CRYPT_PROVIDER_DATA`:

```
GUID policyGUID = WINTRUST_ACTION_GENERIC_VERIFY_V2;
WINTRUST_DATA trustData;
// omitted: prepare trustData

DWORD lStatus = ::WinVerifyTrust( NULL, &policyGUID, &trustData );

if( lStatus == ERROR_SUCCESS )
{
    CRYPT_PROVIDER_DATA* pData = ::WTHelperProvDataFromStateData( trustData.hWVTStateData ); 

    if( pData && pData->pPDSip && pData->pPDSip->psIndirectData && 
        pData->pPDSip->psIndirectData->DigestAlgorithm.pszObjId )
    {
        CRYPT_ALGORITHM_IDENTIFIER const& sigAlgo = pData->pPDSip->psIndirectData->DigestAlgorithm;

        PCCRYPT_OID_INFO pCOI = ::CryptFindOIDInfo( CRYPT_OID_INFO_OID_KEY, sigAlgo.pszObjId, 0 ); 

        if(pCOI && pCOI->pwszName)
        {
            _tprintf(_T("%ls"), pCOI->pwszName);
        }
        else
        {
            _tprintf(_T("%hs"), sigAlgo.pszObjId);
        }
    }
}
```

**Note:** Detailed error checking omitted for brevity!

**Note2:** From Win 8 onwards (and patched Win 7), `WinVerifyTrust` can be used to verify and get information about multiple signatures of a file, more info in [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24892531/7571258).