# Get multiple X509Certificate2Collection objects from a signed EXE with multiple certificates (c#)

Tags: c#, .net, certificate, digital-signature

I'm trying to use the `X509Certificate2Collection` from the .NET library. 
I have an EXE; if I go to Windows Explorer and check the digital signature of the EXE file I see two entries.

When I use the code below:

```
var certificationCollection = new X509Certificate2Collection();
certificationCollection.Import(filePath);
```

and try to enumerate the certificates. I only see one of the certificates. Is there anyway I can get all them?

Comment: X509 certificate is a text file and you should be able to open file with notepad to check contents

Comment: I found what I was trying to do in here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21547311/code-signing-an-executable-twice

Answer (score 0):

Try to search by its name.

- var certificate = collection.Find(X509FindType.FindBySubjectName, certificateName, false);

Answer (score 0):

I don't think .NET supports this (yet).  You can use dllimport of WinVerifyTrust to retrieve all of the certificates from a signed assembly.  I use this native call to get a list of all the certs, the time they were signed, and the hash algorithm used.